# C# Optimal way of custom type conversion

Tags: c#, oop

For example, I have a class

```
public class PackageDimentionsString
{       
    public string Width { get; set; }

    public string Height { get; set; }

    public string Length { get; set; }

    public string Weight { get; set; }

}
```

Which I need to use in some cases and its logical (but not property types) clone which look's like this

```
public class PackageDimentionsDecimal
{       
    public decimal Width { get; set; }

    public decimal Height { get; set; }

    public decimal Length { get; set; }

    public decimal Weight { get; set; }
}
```

But they represent a single entity, so I need to cast them to each other really often.
The question is: what is the optimal and cleanest way of conversion? Extension method? Property that will return the brother object? Or any other options?

Comment: Why do you need to cast them often? Why do you not just use the decimal version always and parse to or from string if necessary?

Comment: Do you mean by string that it will contain same value but as a string type? I mean if PackageDimentionsDecimal.Width = 1.0, will the string Width be equal to 1.0 or one?

Comment: I think the cleanest way is to always use the decimal type. You can easily convert to string if needed...

Comment: Yes, I can use decimal and convert to string if needed, but this requires extra code space to convert each property + culture invariant + decimal spaces. My point is to use single method or property like public class 'PackageDimentionsDecimal
{
 public PackageDimentionsString GetString {...}
}'
Some option which closer to @KevinSmith variant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using AutoMapper (offload the work on to someone else)

```
using System;
using AutoMapper;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<PackageDimentionsString, PackageDimentionsDecimal>());

        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        var m1 = new PackageDimentionsString
        {
            Width = "1000",
            Height = "4000",
            Length = "3302",
            Weight = "445"
        };
        var m2 = mapper.Map<PackageDimentionsString, PackageDimentionsDecimal>(m1);

        Console.WriteLine(m2.Width);
        Console.WriteLine(m2.Height);
        Console.WriteLine(m2.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(m2.Weight);
    }
}

public class PackageDimentionsString
{       
    public string Width { get; set; }

    public string Height { get; set; }

    public string Length { get; set; }

    public string Weight { get; set; }

}

public class PackageDimentionsDecimal
{       
    public decimal Width { get; set; }

    public decimal Height { get; set; }

    public decimal Length { get; set; }

    public decimal Weight { get; set; }
}
```

This will output:

```
1000
4000
3302
445
```

Comment: Is there some option to use it if properties don't have exactly same names?

Comment: Yeah you can create conventions, say you have underscores or prefixes etc... Can also just do explicit mapping too

Answer (score 0):

How about doing this

```
public class PackageDimentions
{
    public dynamic Width { get; set; }

    public dynamic Height { get; set; }

    public dynamic Length { get; set; }

    public dynamic Weight { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
var dimensionDecimal = new PackageDimentions() { Width=100.00, Height =100.00,Length =100.00, Weight =100.00};
var dimensionString = new PackageDimentions() { Width = "100.00", Height = "100.00", Length = "100.00", Weight = "100.00" };
```

You could do this for any types